# RestKit mapping nested properties fails

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data, restkit-0.20

I've got the following JSON payload:

```
"user": {
  "id": 1,
  "username": "bla",
  "first_name": "bla",
  "self": {
    "info": "MyInfo",
    "website": "MyWebsite"
  },
  //... some more properties doesn't matter
}
```

I try to map that nested object `self` into the user model as well and did the following property mappings:

```
mapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(
            ["id"                : "id",
             "username"          : "username",
             "first_name"        : "firstname",
             "self.info"         : "info",
             "self.website"      : "website"])
```

Now when I trigger a GET - request everything maps fine instead of the nested properties `self.info` and `self.website`. When I do a relationship mapping it works as well but I need a separate model which is a bit ugly for these informations.

I'm using RestKit 0.25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just encountered that the problem relies to the method `[object valueForKeyPath:]` which RestKit uses for its mappings. This method returns the object itself when it gets called with `self` so when I change the JSON keyPath to something different e.g. `personal.info` it works as expected! I think this has changed in a recent RestKit release because another app using RestKit 0.23.x works with a `self` keypath.